# textcat -> architecture extra fields not permitted

Tags: python, pycharm, data-analysis, spacy

I've been trying to practise what I've learned from this tutorial:(https://realpython.com/sentiment-analysis-python/) using PyCharm.

And this line:

```
textcat.add_label("pos")
```

generated a warning:
**Cannot find reference 'add_label' in '(Doc) -> Doc | (Doc) -> Doc'**

I understand that this is because "**nlp.create_pipe()**" generates a Doc not a string, but (essentially because I don't know what to do in this case!) I ran the script anyway, but then I got the an error from this line:

```
textcat = nlp.create_pipe("textcat", config={"architecture": "simple_cnn"})
```

Error msg:

```
raise ConfigValidationError(
thinc.config.ConfigValidationError:

Config validation error

textcat -> architecture extra fields not permitted

{'nlp': <spacy.lang.en.English object at 0x0000015E74F625E0>, 'name': 'textcat', 'architecture': 'simple_cnn', 'model': {'@architectures': 'spacy.TextCatEnsemble.v2', 'linear_model': {'@architectures': 'spacy.TextCatBOW.v1', 'exclusive_classes': True, 'ngram_size': 1, 'no_output_layer': False}, 'tok2vec': {'@architectures': 'spacy.Tok2Vec.v2', 'embed': {'@architectures': 'spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v1', 'width': 64, 'rows': [2000, 2000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000], 'attrs': ['ORTH', 'LOWER', 'PREFIX', 'SUFFIX', 'SHAPE', 'ID'], 'include_static_vectors': False}, 'encode': {'@architectures': 'spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2', 'width': 64, 'window_size': 1, 'maxout_pieces': 3, 'depth': 2}}}, 'threshold': 0.5, '@factories': 'textcat'}
```

I'm using:

- Pycharm v: 2019.3.4
- python v: 3.8.6
- spaCy v: 3.0.5

Comment: It looks like the tutorial is for spaCy v2, but you're using v3. The way pipelines are added has changed significantly in v3; I'd recommend you take a look at the quickstart and follow that, it can generate a textcat example. https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart

Comment: Indeed, you're right sir, it was because I'm using a newer spacy version than the author of the tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Man! Did the that full spaCy upgrade really obliterate that tutorial or what...

There's a couple things you might be able to get around. I haven't fully fixed that broken tutorial. It's on the To-Do list. However, I did get around the exact issue you're having.

```
textcat = nlp.create_pipe("textcat", config={"architecture": "simple_cnn"})
```

This `create_pipe` behavior has been deprecated so you can just directly add to the workflow with `add_pipe`. So one thing you could do is the following:

```
from spacy.pipeline.textcat import single_label_cnn_config

<more good code>

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
if "textcat" not in nlp.pipe_names:
     nlp.add_pipe('textcat', config=single_label_cnn_config, last=True)
textcat = nlp.get_pipe('textcat')
textcat.add_label("pos")
textcat.add_label("neg")
```

Let me know if this makes sense and helps. I'll try to revamp the tutorial entirely from spaCy in the coming weeks.

Comment: Thank you sir for replying, but unfortunately, more errors came up and as I'm entirely new, I couldn't resolve them, so I downgraded again to spacy 2.3.5, but I'll keep an eye on your tutorial since it's so clear for a beginner like me, and I'll answer my question here with the new tutorial.

Comment: Hi, I tried using your solution for add_pipe but got the following error (Spacy 3.0.6):

ValueError: [E962] Received incorrect config for pipe 'textcat'. Expected dict, got: <class 'str'>.

Comment: @jlarks32 Hi! I have the same problem as previous commentator. Please update your answer if you know how to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have worked with `spacy 3.1.0`,

```
import en_core_web_md # or skip, see below
from spacy.pipeline.textcat import Config, single_label_cnn_config

nlp = en_core_web_md.load() # or nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

config = Config().from_str(single_label_cnn_config)
if "textcat" not in nlp.pipe_names:
     nlp.add_pipe('textcat', config=config, last=True)

nlp.pipe_names
# ['tok2vec', 'tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner', 'textcat']
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @polm23, the whole problem was because I'm using a newer spaCy version than the author of the tutorial.

mine: 3.0.5
author: 2.3.2

For now, I've just downgraded my spacy to be able to follow up with the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which works in spacy 3.x:

```
# Import spaCy, load large model (folders) which is in project path
import spacy
nlp= spacy.load(r'en_core_web_lg\en_core_web_lg-3.1.0')

# Adding the built-in textcat component to the pipeline.
textcat = nlp.add_pipe("textcat")
nlp.pipe_names

# Adding the labels to textcat
textcat.add_label("pos")
textcat.add_label("neg")

print(nlp.pipe_names)
# ['tok2vec', 'tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner', 'textcat']
```

Answer (score 0):

textcat -> architecture extra fields not permitted in spaCy Error got Solved. This problem will be solved by downgrading the version of spaCY. Run this code to downgrade the spaCy Version to 2.3.6

```
pip install -U spacy==2.3.6
```

This is work for me. Hope this will also help you.