# Textcat in spacy 3.X

Tags: python, spacy

i'm working with Spacy and streamlit to build a fake news classifier. I have upgraded spacy to the 3.X version and i know they changed alot some features. This is why i'm trying to adapt the old textcat create_pipe and nlp.update but i keep getting errors.

```
textcat=nlp.create_pipe( "textcat", config={"exclusive_classes": True, "architecture": "simple_cnn"})
nlp.add_pipe(textcat, last=True)
nlp.pipe_names

textcat.add_label("REAL")
textcat.add_label("FAKE")

    for i in range(n_iter):
        losses = {}
        batches = minibatch(train_data, size=compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.2,
                       losses=losses)
```

but i keep getting the same error about textcat -> architecture        extra fields not permitted and textcat -> exclusive_classes   extra fields not permitted.

I tried the workaround suggested on another post ([textcat -> architecture extra fields not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790649/textcat-architecture-extra-fields-not-permitted))

```
# Import spaCy, load large model (folders) which is in project path
import spacy
nlp= spacy.load(r'en_core_web_lg\en_core_web_lg-3.1.0')

# Adding the built-in textcat component to the pipeline.
textcat = nlp.add_pipe("textcat")
nlp.pipe_names

# Adding the labels to textcat
textcat.add_label("pos")
textcat.add_label("neg")
```

but without any specific luck, has anyone encountered any specific way to update old code in the new version?